# TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryView' of undefined

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3, couchbase-lite

I am trying to filter items from the CBdatabase check my when I call this function I am getting error as cannot read property 'queryView' of undefined

```
refresh() {
        this.couchbase.getDatabase().queryView("_design/Tickets1", "items", {}).then((result: any) => {
            this.items = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                this.items.push(result.rows[i].value);
            }
        }, error => {
            console.error("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
```

I am very new to couchDB any help

Comment: 'this.couchbase.getDatabase()' is undefined. Are you sure this method exists? Which plugin/module are you using for access couchdbase? Please provide your entire. ts file (with imports, constructor, etc).

Comment: This is what i see in my `"cordova-couchbase": "^1.0.0",`

Comment: Please provide the entire code from the component.

Answer (score 0):

This comes from running ionic in a browser.  Couchbase Mobile doesn't currently support that.  You need to run on an actual device or emulator.

Here are steps to get an example running:

```
git clone https://github.com/couchbaselabs/todolite-ionic2.git
cd todolite-ionic2/
npm install
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

— edit package.json and delete the following:

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin.git",
      "id": "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap"
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    {
      "platform": "ios",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "ios"
    },
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],

ionic cordova plugin add couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin
npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest
npm install --save-dev @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular @ionic/cli-
plugin-cordova
npm install --save sw-toolbox
```

— In the process of doing the npm installs, you’ll get asked about two more packages, as shown here.  Answer Y to both.

```
Looks like this is an Ionic Angular project, would you like to install @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular and continue? (Y/n) 


? The plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova is not installed. Would you like to install it and continue? (Y/n) 

cd src/app/
git mv main.dev.ts main.ts
git rm main.prod.ts 
cd ../..

ionic cordova run android --device
```

If you run into problems after that last step, run

```
cordova -d run android --device
```

to get info on what's wrong.